# HWA: instantiating RenderTargetBitmap throws RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD even in UI thread

Tags: c#, uwp, rendertargetbitmap

I'm trying to use `RenderTargetBitmap` to get a screenshot of a Windows Hosted Web App (HWA) window, but I can't seem to instantiate it when handling a request from the Javascript web app running on the HWA app:

```
public async Task<IBuffer> CaptureScreenshotToFileAsync(uint thumbnailWidth, uint thumbnailHeight, string fileName)
{
    // Throws RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD
    RenderTargetBitmap screenshotBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();

    // Assumed that this was a background thread, but...
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        // Surprisingly same thread as above, naturally also throws RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD
        RenderTargetBitmap screenshotBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();            
    });
}
```

In both cases, this is thrown:

```
System.Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E    (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
       at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap..ctor()
```

By the way, if I do the following from a background thread in a standard UWP app, it works as expected:

```
public MainPage()
{
    // UI thread

    Task.Run(() => {
        // Background thread
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            // Back in UI thread.
            RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(); // doesn't throw.
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone explain:

- Why the instantiation of `RenderTargetBitmap` fails in the "UI" thread in a HWA app?
- Why a web request from Javascript is handled by the "UI" thread of the HWA app (bonus)?

Comment: From the bottom snippet we can tell on what thread the caller of this code runs, the MainPage constructor always runs on the UI thread.  We can't tell from the failure case, but the exception does not leave much to imagination, other than what repro code would look like.  It doesn't.